# Facebook's share opens in facebook's browser and can not be catch by Android intent-filter

Tags: android, facebook

There is Android App that can share posts on facebook.
The share has the like (http://website.com/blablabla?panel=clips&clip_id=3155657)
When user click on this link using android device and having APP intalled he saw dialog "Complete action using" browser/app.
Manifest has:

```
<intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="site.com"
                    android:pathPattern=".*"></data>
                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.site.com"
                    android:pathPattern=".*"></data>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            </intent-filter>
```

It worked correct till last days.
Now facebook' shares not working because facebook open the link in it's own browser:
[image]

And only after click on "Open in Browser" you can see Choosing Dialog.

How to avoid this facebook's browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is you can not. 
You need make facebook application notice web, iOS or Android and only after that facebook will redirect users to correct place